# plot a point on top on line chart in chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using chartJs to generate charts for an application I am working.

I can generate line charts using type : line

```html
new Chart(document.getElementById("total-chart"), {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: [ {!! $dates_string !!} ],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            data: [ {!! $totals_string !!} ],
                            label: 'Totals',
                            // steppedLine: true,
                            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                            labels: [ {!! $dates_string !!} ],
                            pointRadius: 1,
                            fill: false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Total'
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        intersect: false,
                        mode: 'index'
                    },
                    animation: {
                        duration: 0
                    }
                }
            });
```

It generates line chart

[image]

I want to show one or more dots/points on top of this line to indicate other related events on particular dates.

I have searched before posting question but there is very less documentation on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As of now best solution I can get is to use mix line graph with bubble graph by adding dataset like this

```html
new Chart(document.getElementById("total-chart"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [ {!! $dates_string !!} ],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [ {!! $totals_string !!} ],
                label: 'Totals',
                // steppedLine: true,
                borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                labels: [ {!! $dates_string !!} ],
                pointRadius: 1,
                fill: false
            },
            {
                data: [ {
                    x: '2018-01-18',
                    y: 24500,
                    r: 5
                } ],
                label: ['Diff'],
                // steppedLine: true,
                backgroundColor: "#cd2026",
                type: 'bubble'
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Total'
        },
        tooltips: {
            intersect: false,
            mode: 'index'
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 0
        }
    }
);
```

result looks somewhat like this.

However label for bubble is funny since I have non numerical x axis. it shows only why mouse is hovered right on x -axis . rest all works as expected

[image]